# incorrect checksum for freed object on large input

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, malloc

I've written a program which computes the number of inversions in a .txt file (first number - amount of numbers, than go numbers themselves). On small input (5 or 10 numbers) it works fine, but when the input is 100,000 numbers (and each number less than 100,000) I get the following error:

```
incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug***
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long int merge(int *arr, const int start, const int half, const int end)
{
        int s=start;
        int i=0;
        int cinv=0;
        int j=half+1;
        int* barr = new int[end+start-1];

        while((s<=half)&&(j<=end)){
                if(arr[s]<=arr[j]){
                        barr[i]=arr[s];
                        s++;

                }
                else{
                        barr[i]=arr[j];
                        j++;
                        cinv++;
                }
                i++;
        }

        if(s>half){
                for(int k = j;k<=end;k++){
                        barr[i]=arr[k];
                        i++;
                }
        }
        else{
                for(int k=s;k<=half;k++){
                        barr[i]=arr[k];
                        i++;
                }
        }

        for(int k=0;k<=end-start;k++) {
                arr[k+start]=barr[k];
        }
        delete[] barr;
        return cinv;
}

long int mergesort(int* arr, int start, int end){
    int half=(start+end)/2;
    long int cinv=0;

    if (start<end){
        cinv+=mergesort(arr, start, half);
        cinv+=mergesort(arr, half+1, end);
        cinv+=merge(arr, start, half, end);
        return cinv;
    }

    return cinv;
}

int main(){
    int len;
    freopen("input.txt", "rt", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "wt", stdout);
    scanf("%d", &len);
    int *arr= new int[len];

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    long int cinv=mergesort(arr, 0, len-1);

    printf("\nInversions with merge=%ld", cinv);

    delete [] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe it would be appropriate to add the 'c' Tag as well, since this code is absolutely not C++, but rather C.

Comment: What is the point of the array `barr` in `main()`? You initialize it, assign ints to it, and then never do anything with it again.

Comment: The dimension in the auxiliary array `barr`in `merge` should be `end - start + 1`.

Comment: @Arcoth `int *arr= new int[len];` not C.

Comment: Memory corruption, apply [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org).

Answer (score 2):

The dimension of your temporary array in `merge`,

```
int* barr = new int[end+start-1];
```

is not correct. When you call `merge` with `start == 0` and `end == 1`, this will yield an array dimension of 0. At the other end of the array, it will allocate twice as much memory as needed. Change this to:

```
int* barr = new int[end - start + 1];
```

What allocating zero bytes does, is implementation-defined. Your program crashes reliably on my Linux platform even with small input arrays.